# Javascript highlight function with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a "simple" highlight function using jQuery. For some reason, it is making my HTML duplicate and I am not sure why. All I would like to do is type search text in the search bar and highlight the text in the tags as I type.

Any thoughts? Desperate...

Here are the HTML and JS

```js
function hiLite(searchWords) {
  if (searchWords) {
    var content = $("p").text();
    var regExp = new RegExp(searchWords, "ig");
    var matches = content.match(regExp);
    if (matches) {
      $("p").html(content.replace(regExp, function(match) {
        return "<span class='highlight'>" + match + "</span>";
      }));
    } else {
      $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    }
  } else {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
  }
};
$("#searchBar").keyup(function() {
  var userInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  hiLite(userInput);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="photo_filter.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="search">Search:
    <input type="text" id="searchBar">
  </div>
  <div id="results">
    <p>some text is here</p>
    <p>other kinds</p>
    <p>even more</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your greatest issue is that you are selecting ALL `<p>` tags at once, when you really need to evaluate each of them individually.

If I have 3 `<p>` tags, and I do this:
`$('p').html('I am a p tag!!');` - Then every single `<p>` tag will be affected.

Similarly, if I do this:
`var content = $('p').text();` - Then `content` equals this `"some text is hereother kindseven more"`, which is the text from *every single* `<p>` tag. That's not good!

Try this:

```
function hiLite(searchWords) {
    if (searchWords) {
        $('p').each(function(index, single_p) {
            var text = $(single_p).text(); // .text() does not include html, does not include any former <spans>
            $(single_p).html(text); // reset <p> html to be only the text from previous line
            var regExp = new RegExp(searchWords, "ig");

            var new_text = text.replace(regExp, '<span class="highlight">' + searchWords + '</span>'); // create new text with HTML highlight
            $(single_p).html(new_text); // update DOM with our new HTML
        });
    }
};


$("#searchBar").keyup(function() {
    var userInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    hiLite(userInput);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2:

Added condition to highlight text based on search text

**JS Code:**

```
 function hiLite(searchWords){

        if(searchWords){
        var content = $("p").text();
        var regExp = new RegExp(searchWords, "ig");
        var matches = content.match(regExp);

       if(matches){
                        $('#results p').each(function() {
                        var test = '<span class="highlight">'+searchWords+'</span>';
                        var text = $(this).text();
                        $(this).html(text.replace(regExp, test)); 
                    });
            }

        } 
    };


$("#searchBar").keyup(function(){
 var userInput = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 hiLite(userInput); 
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="search">Search:     
<input type="text" id="searchBar">    
</div>

<div id="results">

    <p>some text is here</p>
    <p>other kinds</p>
    <p>even more</p>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlight{
  color:red
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/7637/):